How many days do single-night night train trips count as with Interrail Flexi Passes?
I'm travelling from Linköping to Brussels by train, and for the section between Linköping and Hamburg I'm considering taking either Snälltåget or the SJ EuroNight train that goes between Stockholm and Berlin. With either, I have the option of using an Interrail pass in addition to a surcharge for a "seat" reservation. Both of them leave Linköping C in the evening before midnight and arrive at Hamburg Hbf in the morning after midnight.
Everything already written makes sense to me, but what I don't understand is how many days this one-night night train ride counts as. Given that Interrail tickets operate on a fixed number of days-basis, this feels very relevant. So, if I were to use an Interrail Flexi Pass for this trip, how many days would going from Linköping C to Hamburg Hbf consume? Additionally, if it only "consumes" one day, would the "consumed" day be the one I depart Linköping or the one I arrive in Hamburg?

From the faq:

When travelling on a night train that leaves on one day and arrives the next, you only have to spend 1 travel day: the day of departure

